# HTTP codes custom descriptions

Tags: http, rfc

Could I send this response

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Nobody home
```

instead of

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not found
```

Or it is RFC violation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html), especially at this quote:

> The reason phrases listed here are only recommendations -- they MAY be
>   replaced by local equivalents without affecting the protocol.

If they can be replaced with local variants they can be replaced with other messages as well, however this is not recommended. A better idea might to provide a custom code (with appropriate class of course e.g. `4XX`) along with good reason phrase.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question. But i am not sure about defining custom codes. I think you must register rfc standard to describe codes and only next use it.

Comment: Ok, you can include a status line you need. When it comes to custom code you can easily send 499 e.g. and it's all fine - no need to register it via RFC.

Comment: Yep. Thank for answer.